# Interior of the set {1/n}

Tags: real-analysis

What is the interior of the set {1/n} where n is a natural number?
For me by considering the definition I think the interior is an empty set.Am I right here?

Comment: As a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (with the standard topology), yes, the interior is empty. If the ambient space is something else, it may be an open set.

Answer (score 4):

The interior of a set is the union of all open sets contained in the set. This really depends on the topology you consider on $K=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, but assuming you are considering $K\subset\mathbb{R}$, with the standard topology.

In which case, $K$ contains no open sets, and thus yes you are correct and the interior is empty.